# In tel Wi-Fi 6 AX200 stopped working on 22.04 after a few days from installation

Tags: wireless, lubuntu, iwlwifi, msi, linux-headers

After installing ubuntu 22.04 on my PC, my wifi worked a few days but won't work any more. I updated the driver to no avail.

```
[    2.604117] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    2.609136] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[    2.609148] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 89.3.35.37
[    2.609461] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: loaded firmware version 66.f1c864e0.0 cc-a0-66.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    2.713334] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz, REV=0x340
[    2.799160] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: retry init count 0
[    2.799201] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz, REV=0x340
[    2.885144] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: retry init count 1
[    2.885170] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz, REV=0x340
[    2.971024] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: retry init count 2
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `sudo dmesg | grep iwl` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Is this a dual boot with Windows? Please turn off Fast Boot: https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi#about_dual-boot_with_windows_and_fast-boot_enabled

Comment: Thanks a lot! turning off Fast Boot solved the issue, I am able to connect wifi. And yes, it is a dual boot but from two separate drives.

Comment: I shall propose an answer that I hope you will accept. The searchable answer will help others with the same issue. I'm glad it's working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your message log, we see:

> iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: retry init count 2

It is often the case that a failure to initialize is because, in a dual boot environment, Windows doesn't really shut down the entire system, but leaves things partially running so you can start the machine faster again. Within Windows, disable the “Fast Startup” option in “Shutdown Settings”. Reboot.

Reference: https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi#about_dual-boot_with_windows_and_fast-boot_enabled

Comment: This was the case for me. And FWIW this was because I had previously shut down the computer from Windows (as opposed to what I normally do, which is only restart and sleep the machine). So I restarted from Windows and when I booted into Ubuntu the wifi was back to working. I have heard that Windows only fully resets when it restarts (or holding shift while shutting down) and this would support that theory.